# What does x[item] means?

Tags: python, list, iteration

In this code:

```
x = [0,1,2]

for item in range(len(x)):
    print x[item]
```

The result printed is:

```
0 1 2
```

What does x[item] do? What does it mean?

Comment: `x` is your list, `item` - is an index of some value

Comment: I think you should start reading a tutorial. The [official one](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) is quite good.

Comment: Also stop reading wherever you got that from unless the next paragraph is *"of course you'd never actually do that because `for item in x: print item` does the same thing and you should be using Python 3.x so that's `print(item)`"*.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a list. `item` is index that ranges from `0` to length of list `x` -1 .

`x[item]` access the value at index `item` in list `x`.

Answer (score 0):

X is variable that contains 3 values in it, this type of variables are called array or list that can hold multiple values instead of single. 
To access the values of x you need to access index of this variable which starts from 0 and ends to n-1 where n is numbers of values your variable has. 
For e.g you have 3 values here so your n will be (3-1) 2 which is also called as length or size interchangeably.
So to access values of x , we defined a temporary indexer which is 'item'.
x[items] goes from 0 to n-1 values and simply print them .
Hope you got the concept.

Answer (score 0):

x is a list that has three values in it. Every time the loop runs it will set the variable 'item' to the current number of times the loop has run (since there are three values in the list it will be 0, then 1, then 2). When printing x[0], it will print the first item in the list. So when you  print x[item], it will print the 1st item in the list, then the 1st, then 2nd, then third.

Read up on lists and for loops to learn more.